# How I can copy specific rows from datagrad view 1 to datagradview 2 (in data bound )

Tags: vb.net

How can I copy specific rows from datagradview1 to datagradview2 which is data bound?

I want to select more rows from DGV1 to copy into DGV2 but data bound

I used this code but it selects one row only

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    DataGridView2.Columns.Clear()
    For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        DataGridView2.Columns.Add(DirectCast(Col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
    Next

    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value).ToArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: `i used these code but it select one row only`, because of `DataGridView1.CurrentRow`, you are telling it only current row...If you want to add more than one, you can look at [DataGridView.SelectedRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=netframework-4.8) to go through. Also you mentioned `is data bound` can you show how you are adding the data sources and how you are populating them?

Comment: i used DataGridView1.rows(0)  and not copy just first row and i use forloop DataGridView1.rows(E) but it will go to select all row and i need specific rows

Comment: Did you look into my suggestion?

Comment: yaa but i can't find solve from my problem

Answer (score 0):

I got your questions, and here you the solution:

You should split your great code into two parts, the 1st part you should put this code in the Form_Load, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView2.Columns.Clear()
    For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        DataGridView2.Columns.Add(DirectCast(Col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
    Next
End Sub
```

The 2nd part, will be coded in the button event, such as this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value).ToArray)
End Sub
```

Now every thing is fine, I have tested it successfully.

Comment: i am sorry pro but this is message "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

Comment: @MohamedFaysal Please re-read my comment from above, `Also you mentioned is data bound can you show how you are adding the data sources and how you are populating them?` If you can't provide that, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Hi bro, blessed Friday. First of all, I'd like to ensure you that the 2nd datagridview is not bounded to any source.I test it and it works 100% , and I hope it works for you as well. Best ^_^ Regards.